# Flutter widget is refreshed after popping it when using provider

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I hope I will be able to explain it correctly, but my issue is basically that after popping from tab A to ExpandItemTab, ExpandItemTab is rebuilt event after pop.

After I delete the item from the item's tab (ExpandItemTab) I get `StateError (Bad state: No element)`  because `context.watch<MyItemsProvider>().getItem(widget.itemId)` does not contain the item anymore after provider refresh since it was deleted, but I do not need it to reload (but I need it to reload in other cases, e.g. when I edit the item).

How can I just pop the current page after the item is deleted and not trigger the provider?

I guess I could call `context.read<MyItemsProvider>().refreshItems()` in tab A, but I do not need to do it every time (I would then need to pass a parameter to pop to indicate whether reload is needed). Also, it seems more correct to do reload at the same place update is done.

So the code for ExpandItemTab is:

```
imports ...

class ExpandItemTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final String itemId;

  const ExpandItemTab({super.key, required this.itemId});

  @override
  State<ExpandItemTab> createState() {
    return _ExpandItemTabState();
  }
}

class _ExpandItemTabState extends State<ExpandItemTab> {
  final _databaseRepo = DatabaseRepository();

  void _delete(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
        return DeleteDialog(
          content: 'Are you sure you want to delete the item?',
          delete: () {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
            _databaseRepo.deleteItem(widget.itemId).then(
                  (doc) => {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    // I would expect that this refresh would not trigger a rebuild of the current page (_ExpandItemTabState)
                    // The issue is that since after this refresh build() is called I am getting StateError (Bad state: No element) since context.watch<MyItemsProvider>().getItem(widget.itemId) does not contain the item anymore since it was deleted
                    context.read<MyItemsProvider>().refreshItems(),
                    showSuccessSnackBar(
                      context,
                      'Item deleted.',
                      2,
                    ),
                  },
                );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // this is called after context.read<MyItemsProvider>().refreshItems() but fails since item is no longer there. But I would like this not to be called after pop.
    Outfit item = context.watch<MyItemsProvider>().getItem(widget.itemId);

    return Material(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: const AppBarButton(text: 'Delete'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _delete(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Text(item.imageUrl),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code for provider:

```
class MyItemsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _databaseRepo = DatabaseItemsRepository();

  List<Outfit> _myItems = [];

  List<Outfit> get getMyItems => _myItems;

  Outfit getItem(String id) {
    return _myItems.firstWhere((element) => element.id == id);
  }

  Future<void> refreshItems() async {
    List<Outfit> myItems = await _databaseRepo.getCurrentUserItems();
    _myItems = myItems;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you're using Provider wrong. I don't have time to fix it for you, but I never use getter functions with provider just something like this context.read<FilterProvider>().filter wich gives back the object directly. I never use context.watch just Consumer. I suggest you take a look at the Provider description again on pub.dev and probably using Consumer will have the desired outcome.